# Working with JWT, how to check for Authorization-Header?

Tags: go, header, authorization, jwt

I'm completely new to working with JWT and I'm struggling at a certain point:

With AJAX requests I can set the authorization-header before the request...ok.

How do I use the JWT for "normal" requests? F.e. when reloading the page or simply following a link.

F.e. if a user isn't logged in, I want to redirect him to a landing-page.

On the server-side I have middleware that checks the JWT from the authorization-header and then either grants permission or redirects to the landing-page, but ofc currently I'm always getting the landing-page, because there's no authorization-header for non-AJAX requests.

I'm storing the JWT in localstorage.

What am I missing?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the JWT in a Cookie. This way they will be sent with every request (including "normal" ones). Here is a code snippet from one of my projects:

```
func loginHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ...
    accessToken := newAccessToken(...) // returns a JWT with fields .Token and .Expires
    cookie := &http.Cookie{
        Name:     "access_token",
        Value:    accessToken.Token,
        HttpOnly: true,
        Secure:true,
        Expires: time.Unix(accessToken.Expires, 0),
        Path:    "/",
    }
    http.SetCookie(w, cookie)
    ...
}
```

And to retreive the token:

```
func someHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    cookie, err := r.Cookie("access_token")
    if err != nil {
        // handle missing cookie
    }
    accessToken := cookie.Value
    ...
}
```

Note that Cookies are vulnerable to CSRF Attacks.

Further reading: [Where to Store your JWTs – Cookies vs HTML5 Web Storage](https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage)

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can't set it for normal requests as it's an application layer authentication that can only be handled in JS. You should provide and endpoint that doesn't require authentication and serves the page, then in JS you should check if there's a stored JWT and act accordingly (either go to login page or load the app). 
It strongly depends on your JS frontend framework.

Comment: hm..not using a frontend framework like angular or react. trying to avoid it :(. I like having the server render the views and simply enhance the UI/UX with ajax calls. But i'm starting to sense i won't get far with it using JWT instead of a "classic" authorization method.

Comment: Ok this is not a problem, you still have to act as i described above. The JWT must be set in the headers by the JS application code upon Ajax calls. I'm sorry but no JWT in link following... you must build a complete webapp with routing and views to handle page changes.

Answer (score 0):

Look at JSON Web Token RFC https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519

> JSON Web Token (JWT) is a compact claims representation format intended for space constrained environments such as HTTP Authorization headers and URI query parameters

there is no obligation to use a header. You can send the JWT as a query param in URL or a field  in a POST form.

For links, just include the JWT as a param `url?JWT=...`

In your server you have to deal with all the ways of receiving  JWT

Comment: any security issues sending the token as a parameter? I mean..besides looking ugly i don't see how it could be dangerous compared to a header attribute?

Comment: if an attacker intercepts your connection he will see the headers and payload, both  forms and with ajax. Use https in any case. Also avoid public links with authenticabtion información, or use a short expiration time

Comment: Pedro's answer is a correct option, however it's not so "happy". You could incur in useless unauthorized requests (bad ux) when the token expires. Letting the JS handle requests will allow you to handle token renewal and other issues in a user transparent way.

Comment: Be careful using query parameters containing JWTs. Typically, requests are logged, along with the query parameters. If your JWTs are signed but not encrypted, they can leak sensitive information to everyone who has read-access to the log files. They might also be useful for insider attacks if your JWTs are bearer tokens. Session hijacking might be too easy.

Comment: Form fields (i.e. request entity content) and cookies are a wiser alternative to using query parameters for JWTs. (I'm assuming you're using https, of course). Form values and cookies do not usually get logged in the access logs.